# Flutter changing the internationalization

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, internationalization

I followed the [Flutter Internationalization tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) but now I'm a bit stuck with a problem concerning changing the language on the fly, regardless of the device.
Suppose my app supports the following languages

- English
- Dutch
- Spanish
- Portuguese
- German
- Chinese

Suppose now that a French speaking user opens the app, then the app language is by default English. But suppose now that this user does not speak English, but he does speak for example Spanish. I now created a settings entry to pick any language among the supported languages such that a user is free to change whichever language fits him best.

But now, when any text is shown, it is done through

```
Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).some_key)
```

This of course falls back to the localizations defined in

```
return MaterialApp(
  ...
  localizationsDelegates: [
    AppLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: Settings.SUPPORTED_LOCALES,
  localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
    for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
      if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode)
        return supportedLocale;
    }
    return supportedLocales.first;
  },
  ...
);
```

With `Settings.SUPPORTED_LOCALES` being

```
static const List<Locale> SUPPORTED_LOCALES = [
  const Locale('en'),
  const Locale('nl'),
  const Locale('de'),
  const Locale('es'),
  const Locale('pt'),
  const Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'zh')
];
```

How could I now instruct the localizations package to pick not the device language any longer, but the user's preferred language?